# What's the best way to create submodules from within modules in Marionette?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, backbone.js, marionette

I'm building an application that can consists of multiple modules (and some modules will even have sub-modules). When the application is instantiated, I pass in an object the describes the modules that I'd like to be active for that application instance (myApp), and the class those modules should use. The Application then uses a factory object to create the necessary modules. This has worked great as a proof of concept, but **I'm having troubles with creating submodules from within other modules initialize methods and getting those submodules to start up**.

Using the code below, I see the following messages dumped to the console (added numbers for reference).

1. ( Some.Module.Class ) moduleA initialize
2. ( Some.Module.Class ) moduleB initialize
3. *( Some.SubModule.Class ) moduleB initialize*
4. ( Some.SubModule.Class ) submoduleB initialize
5. ( Some.Module.Class ) moduleA start
6. ( Some.Module.Class ) moduleB start

What is confusing to me is
1. When the onStart method for moduleB is called, submodules is empty, and no submoduleB doesn't start.
2. Why does line #3 in the console messages appear? It's calling moduleB initialize twice, but with the submodule class?

```
//SUB MODULE
Some.SubModule.Class = Io.Modules.BaseModule.extend({
    __className: "Some.SubModule.Class",
    startWithParent: false,

    onStart: function(options) {
        console.log("(", this.getClassName(), ")", this.moduleName, "start");
    },

    initialize: function(options, moduleName, app) {
        console.log("(", this.getClassName(), ")", this.moduleName, "initialize");
    }

});

// MODULE
Some.Module.Class = Io.Modules.BaseModule.extend({
    __className: "Some.Module.Class",
    startWithParent: false,

    onStart: function(options) {
        console.log("(", this.getClassName(), ")", this.moduleName, "start");
        _.each(this.submodules, function(module) { module.start(); });
    },

    initialize: function(moduleName, app, options) {
        console.log("(", this.getClassName(), ")", this.moduleName, "initialize");
        var moduleFactory = new Io.Factories.ModuleFactory({app:app});
        var fieldConfigurator = moduleFactory.createModule("moduleB.submoduleB", Some.SubModule.Class, {});
    }

});

// APPLICATION
var MyApp = Marionette.Application.extend({
...
    initialize: function(opts) {
        //Create all modules described in the options passed in
    }
    //Start up all modules
    _.each(this.submodules, function(module) { module.start(); });
...
});

var myApp = new MyApp({
    modules: {
        moduleA: {
            "class":Some.Module.Class,
            options:{
                someOption:someValue
            }
        },
        moduleB: {
            "class":Some.Module.Class,
            options:{
                someOption:someValue
            }
        },
        ...     
    }
});

myApp.start();
```

Comment: This may not be what you want to hear but Derick Bailey, the creator of Marionette, has referred to the module system as "a horrible mess". Perhaps you may be better of using something like require js or browserify for module definition. http://derickbailey.com/2014/06/10/browserify-my-new-choice-for-modules-in-a-browser-backbone-app/

Comment: Indeed... Not what I wanted to hear at all. Unfortunately I was intending to  use modules for their ability to act as sub-applications that could be started/stoped and that were tied into the event system, rather than just be resources for a build process. It doesn't sound like browserify is going to solve that problem. Thank you for the heads-up though. It probably wouldn't be too hard to hack something together to do this, just making me question my choice for going with Marionette now.

Comment: I've been using Marionette a while now on a reasonably large application and find it pretty good, mostly for things like the layout view, collection view and composite view. I tried using the module system in the beginning but personally found it convoluted and forced, all the way from implementing a module to the stopping / starting of it.

Comment: Any ideas on another way of handling the lack of sub apps? I see that they are talking about it for version 3, but who know when that's coming. Thanks for the response, btw. Much appreciated.

Comment: @fugged you might want to check out [backbone.geppetto](https://github.com/GeppettoJS/backbone.geppetto), which aims to solve many of the problems with subapps and provide centralized, yet decoupled communication, dependency injection et cetera. It plays nicely with Marionette too and is meant to be used with require/browserify. Disclaimer: I'm a co-author.